# Projection of a vector alongside a unit vector

Tags: linear-algebra

I know that the component of `x` along `u` is $\frac{u.x}{|u|}.$ ($x$,$u$ are both vectors) but my teacher said that this is equal to $u^T x u$ (||u|| = 1). I understand the first formula, But I cant understand the second one well.

Comment: What is $a,b,x$?

Comment: @BigbearZzz sorry, I edited the question

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Well, since $x\cdot u=u^Tx$ and the component of $x$ along $u$ is $$\frac{x\cdot u}{|u|^2}u$$
, if we let $|u|=1$ we'd have
$$\begin{align}
\frac{x\cdot u}{|u|^2}u &= (x\cdot u)u \\ 
&= u^Txu
\end{align}$$

Comment: By the way, $\frac{x\cdot u}{|u|^2}u=(\frac{x\cdot u}{|u|})(\frac{u}{|u|})$, which is the scalar component of $x$ along the direction $u$ times the unit vector $\frac u{|u|}$ pointing in the direction of $u$.